# How to resolve install: omitting directory error?

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, openwrt

I am trying to cross-compile a package in OpenWrt but i am getting this error `install: omitting directory`. Package is enabled in menuconfig.

Comment: Did you find the answer to it? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: are you trying to cross-compile some external package ?

Comment: yeah I have a source code which I made a Makefile for and now I'm trying to compile it but this error shows up. How did you fix it?

Comment: i added my package in the this path openwrt/package and executed make like this "make /package/package_name/compile"

Comment: you can cross-compile your package directly without adding it to openwrt/package directory. Can you name the package which you want to cross-compile ?

Comment: It's a package which I made out of source files (.CPP and headers (.h)). As for compiling that's what I did exactly, I directly added my package to openwrt/package and compiled it. It has something to do with my makefile, precisely in the "define Package_name/install"  part.

Comment: i compiled .c files on ubuntu. try these steps (modify if required). (1)export PATH=toolchain_path/bin/:$PATH, (2) export STAGING_DIR=staging_dir_path, (3) export CROSS=arm-openwrt-linux, (4) export CC=${CROSS}-gcc, (5) export LD=${CROSS}-ld, (6) export AS=${CROSS}-as, (7) export AR=${CROSS}-ar